# SharePoint 2010: Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Could not find any recognizable digits

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Could not find any recognizable digits.

Dos anyone know what this error message means? I'm trying to deploy a feature containing some, content types, list definitions and list instances.

[image: View of the Error List in Visual Studio 2010]

Stack Trace:

```
[FormatException: Could not find any recognizable digits.]

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionFieldsAndContentTypes(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce) +23502762
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce) +138
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce) +25284223
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly) +27336607
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope) +150
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.Add(Guid featureId, Boolean force, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope) +83
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(Guid featid, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope) +699
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivatorItem.BtnActivateFeature_Click(Object objSender, EventArgs evtargs) +140
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full and answered thread can be found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-could-not-find-any-recogni) at sharepoint.stackexchange.com